# I have magento 2.1.9, When add product to cart .It redirects to white blank page

Tags: magento-2.1

I have magento 2.1.9, When  add product to cart .It redirects to white blank page.I have tried all solutions, enabled PHP error reporting but no error any where. tried different browsers.same issue

[image: This is the probleblem]

Comment: Do you have tried 777 permission to var and pub directory recursively...

Comment: did nt tried yet

Answer (score 0):

Try to set developer mode using cli, and check logs, looks like you have some error, but it doesn't displayed becouse of errors hendle settings does not allow.

Comment: tried developer mode  but still no error

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem the issue was with my custom theme JavaScript.

Go to your custom theme directory and remove the JavaScript for the appropriate XML file. And test out which script is messing things up.

Comment: I`m using default Luma theme..will update once check ur solution .there is no log to identify anything

Comment: Check developer tools on chrome and look for errors there.

Comment: nothing there,one strange thing i have noted now is that server time and the log time are not same..seeing live logs with tailf and server time on OS and log time do not match